# regex - find just range of string

Tags: php, regex

I have this string:

```
{category:-}{product}-{rewrite:/}{/:controller}
```

I want to find all substring from `{ to :` and `: to }` and removed it like this:

```
{category}{product}-{rewrite}{controller}
```

my regex is `/:.*}/g` but it select first `:` to last `}` and when i replace it this give it !:

```
{category}
```

Comment: Can you make your specifications a little clearer? Finding "_a substring from `{ to :` and `: to }`_" would result in `{}` for `{category:-}`, right?

Comment: The problem with your sample data is that the behaviour for `{category:-}` is different to that for `{/:controller}`. A regex which converts `{category:-}` to `{category}` will convert `{/:controller}` to `{/}`, not `{controller}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one straightforward approach:

```
$input = "{category:-}{product}-{rewrite:/}{/:controller}";
echo preg_replace("/:[^a-zA-Z0-9]*(?=\})|(?<=\{)[^a-zA-Z0-9]*:/", "", $input);

{category}{product}-{rewrite}{controller}
```

### Demo

The regex pattern I used targets the following:

- colons which are followed only by non alphanumeric characters, followed by closing `}` bracket
- colons which are preceded by only non alphanumeric characters, preceded by opening `{` bracket

Comment: if input like this: `"{category:-}{product}-{rewrite:/}{hhhh:controller}"` not `hhhh` found

Comment: @JMaze Why are you changing your requirements now, or is the issue that you just didn't give us good sample data above?

Comment: @JMaze Your new example is unclear, because it is not clear whether `hhhh` or `controller` is the substring which should be retained.  We would need to know which of the two is the real substring.

Comment: i see. but i assume all character between `{ to :` replaced with `{` and `: to }` replaced with `}`

Comment: Your sample string does not have `to` appearing anywhere.  Can you show us the actual data?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think he means **between** `{` and `:`

Comment: @Nick That's not specific enough, for the reasons I highlighted above.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you're right, on that basis the result should be `{}{}-{}{}`

Comment: @Nick A more important question: cabernet or merlot?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Now you're speaking my language! :) They both have their place...

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So what brought that (somewhat out of the blue) question on?

Comment: I saw that you are a winemaker, so I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will help you with this:

```
$string = '{category:-}{product}-{rewrite:/}{/:controller}'; 
$string = preg_replace("/{([^{]:)*(\w*)(:[^}]*)*}/", '{$2}', $string); 
echo $string;
```

here is the [Demo](http://rextester.com/QWK31661) if you want to try this with multiple variations.